# Linux - Limit USB Device Bandwidth

Tags: linux, usb, bandwidth

I am trying to connect multiple (10-20) USB Wi-Fi Dongles to a single USB port (using an external powered USB HUB), however I am not able to get more than 5-6 devices connected at the same time.

It seems that each dongle is allocating "500-800" Mbps from the total available 5000 Mbps (1x USB3 port), which does not make sense.

My question however would be if there is some way to have the USB port/hub behave as a "Best-Effort" and ignore the allocated bandwidths or simply be able to limit each device to a lower bandwidth such as 20-50 Mbps. I don't need them to perform at full speed.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it will be possible and the reasons are below.

Before going to the reason, lets discuss "Bus Instance".

As per the XHCI spec, "Each Bus Instance (BI) represents a “unit” bandwidth at the speed that the BI supports"

So each of your USB 3.0 port in the hub will have two Bus Instance. Super speed and High speed.

Bandwidth depends on the device attached. If its a USB 2.0 device, it will get at most 480 Mbps bandwidth and for SS device 5 Gbps at most. If multiple device is connected, then it will be completely dependent on the USB controller hardware to divide the bandwidth between the Bus instances.

So basically, I do not think we can do it via software. XHCI specification does not have any command to change bandwidth. We have only command to get bandwidth. Also we do not have any hub requests for bandwidth management of hub ports.